# reading numbers from a file to an array and add a number to each element

Tags: c#, arrays

I want this code to read numbers from a file given by user and write the numbers to an array in order to add another constant value(like 1) to each element and write it back to a file somewhere.

This is my code but I don't know whats wrong with it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reading and Writng Back");
        string[] arr;
        Console.WriteLine("Where the file is located?(Enter the full directory path!)");
        string filePath = Console.ReadLine();
        arr = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        int[] myInts = arr.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        for (int j = 0; j <= myInts.Length; j++)
        {
            myInts[j] += myInts[j + 1];
        }
        string result = string.Join(",", myInts);
        File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Final.txt", result);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "This is my code but I don't know whats wrong with it:" neither do we. You've told us what the desired functionality is but not what's wrong. However you will get an array out of bounds exception.

Comment: By the way the
the input file looks like
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,11,23,24,26373

Comment: use a debugger, try to diagnose where problem is happening

Comment: This code is adding the next element in the array to the current element. It is _not_ adding a constant value.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt also the index `j + 1`

Comment: @mikeTheLiar How can I add a constant value to an element of this array?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format. This is the error when I use a file with these contents: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,11,23,24,26373

Comment: @Amir I'd have to guess it's all those commas.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar   What should I enter instead of comma in order to separate

Comment: @Amir you don't have to use something different, just split the string on the commas. Something like `arr = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Split(',');`

Comment: @mikeTheLiar i tried that but there is no such syntax " .split(',') "

Comment: Could you please write your file-structure within the question? It is not clear how the numbers within the file are delimited, by `,` or new line or ...?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `myInts[j] += myConst;` which is short-version for `myInts[j] = myInts[j] + myConst`;

Or even shorter:

```
myInts = myInts.Select(x => x + myConst).ToArray();
```

Of coruse before writing this to the file you have to convert the array back to `string[]` or something like so:

```
var result = myInts.Select(x => (x + myConst).ToString()).ToArray()
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

This is the error when I use a file with these contents:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,11,23,24,26373

Comment: *Your* code reads its input values via a *new line seperated* format, see `arr = File.ReadAllLines(filePath); int[] myInts = arr.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();`. Seems like you're giving it a file with comma-seperated values?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt What should I do in order to make it read a file with comma-separated values?

Answer (score 1):

You are `adding` the next element rather than a `constant`:

```
myInts[j] = myInts[j] + 1;
```

Also your loop condition will throw an  array out of bounds exception, fix it:

```
for (int j = 0; j < myInts.Length; j++) //just remove "="
```